# Advice for a good conception tool for .NET applications (such as WPF)

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, uml, development-environment

I just know old tools such as [PowerAMC](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/poweramc) or [Rational Rose](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/rose/), are there always adapted tools ?

The objective is to create some base UML schema : use case, class diagram, séquence diagram, composant diagram, deployement diagram. Be able to generate code and reverse engineering would be a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Visualization and Modeling Feature Pack
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460723.aspx